# If kinetic energy is equal to force x distance, does that mean a mass traveling in the vaccum of space keeps getting kenetic energy

Tags: energy

This is something I don't understand about it because if the speed remains constant, nothing changes about the objects energy.

Comment: If the speed remains constant, is there a *net* force acting on the mass?

Answer (score 1):

A mass travelling in vacuum in space does so at constant velocity because there are no forces on it. This means that the product of force times distance is zero, and indeed there is no change in its kinetic energy.

It's important to note that the product of force and displacement is usually known as the **work** performed by that force. By virtue of the [work-energy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29#General_derivation_of_the_work-energy_theorem_for_a_particle), the net work performed by external forces on a given particle is equal to the increase in its kinetic energy. The two concepts are linked but distinct.